# Google authentication in strapi using strapi-google-auth npm package

Tags: axios, google-oauth, strapi

To preface, I'm using strapi v4, react, and astro to build my app, and the plugin giving me trouble is [strapi-google-auth](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-google-auth). I'm trying to implement google authentication into my strapi application but I can't seem to figure out a request error I'm recieving. I've followed the steps up until I have to request the JWT token. So users can log in using google, but I can't get the JWT because of a 400 bad request error.

My front end code:

```
const login = async () => {
      let authCode = queryString.parse(window.location.search)
      console.log(authCode.code)
      let googleAuth = {
        data: {
          code: authCode.code,
        }
      }
      let jwt = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:1338/strapi-google-auth/user-profile', googleAuth)
        .then((res) => setJwt(res.data))
      
    }
```

The error:
`{"data":null,"error":{"status":400,"name":"BadRequestError","message":"Error occured while fetching the user profile","details":null}}`

[image: The problem step]

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I've tried fiddling with the way the payload is formatted, uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin, and running the request through postman.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the `googleAuth` object value to:

```js
// Some code
// ...

let googleAuth = {
  code: authCode.code,
}

let jwt = await axios.post(
  'STRAPI_BACKEND_URL/strapi-google-auth/user-profile',
  googleAuth
).then((res) => setJwt(res.data))
```

The second param for axios post is the `data`, then you can pass the object there.

```js
axios.post('STRAPI_BACKEND_URL/strapi-google-auth/user-profile', {
  code: REDIRECTION_AUTH_CODE
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```